# How to pass a Vue3 Ref variable by reference? (and what the missing "global" variable is)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I wrote the following [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/)/Vue3 component (`TemperatureOutside.vue`)

```
<template>
  <div class='text-large-1 text-weight-bold'>
    {{ temperature }}°
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang='ts'>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { setupMqtt } from './mqtt';

const temperature = ref(-100)
setupMqtt('temperature', temperature)
</script>
```

`setupMqtt` is defined in `mqtt.ts`:

```
import { connect } from 'mqtt'
import { Ref } from 'vue'

export const setupMqtt = (topic: string, data: Ref): void => {
    const client = connect('mqtt://192.168.10.2:1884')
    const topics = [`dash/${topic}`]
    // removed some setup lines that do not matter
    client.on('message', function (topic: string, message: Buffer) {
      // the key line is below
      data.value = JSON.parse(message.toString())
    })
}
```

I wanted to pass `data` and react to the change of its `.value`in the calling component.

My problem: the program runs fine when I comment out `setupMqtt('temperature', temperature)`. If it is present, I get on the console the following breaking error:

```
vue-router.mjs:35 [Vue Router warn]: uncaught error during route navigation:
warn @ vue-router.mjs:35
triggerError @ vue-router.mjs:3439
(anonymous) @ vue-router.mjs:3163
Promise.catch (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.mjs:3157
push @ vue-router.mjs:3089
install @ vue-router.mjs:3520
use @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4349
start @ client-entry.js?t=1663525498443:63
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ client-entry.js?t=1663525498443:82

vue-router.mjs:3441 ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:48:21)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1:28)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js (store.js:8:18)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js (client.js:7:15)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js (index.js:3:20)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
triggerError @ vue-router.mjs:3441
(anonymous) @ vue-router.mjs:3163
Promise.catch (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.mjs:3157
push @ vue-router.mjs:3089
install @ vue-router.mjs:3520
use @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4349
start @ client-entry.js?t=1663525498443:63
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ client-entry.js?t=1663525498443:82

vue-router.mjs:35 [Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:48:21)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1:28)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js (store.js:8:18)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js (client.js:7:15)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
    at node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js (index.js:3:20)
    at __require (chunk-OL3AADLO.js?v=fff356dc:9:50)
```

I fail to understand what the referenced `global` variable is and I fear that my attempt to pass by reference fails miserably somewhere.

Comment: The problem is relevant to this lib and possibly projectsetup, not Vue. The lib is for Node and browser, the error means that it acts or more specifically, its dep (readable-stream)  acts like it's used in Node and tries to access `global` global variable, which doesn't exist in a browser. This shouldn't happen in properly published package so it's the lib to blame. Possibly a different entry point can solve this, try to import ` mqtt/dist/mqtt.js` instead, it's clearly browser build, not sure if it can affect how `readable-stream` works

Comment: @EstusFlask: thank you. I was wondering about this `global` entity so now I know. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`ref()` takes the argument and returns it wrapped within a ref object with a `.value` property. The `.value` property of a ref is reactive.

Could you try changing the `setupMqtt()` function in `TemperatureOutside.vue` file:

```
const temperature = ref(-100);
setupMqtt('temperature', temperature.value);
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass ref value, this defies the purpose of a ref